# scalatest "A stack" should "do something" -- wtf? How is should a method of string?

Tags: scala, scalatest

I'm just starting out with scala here and I'm finding some of the syntax confusing.  For example from the [scalatest main page](http://www.scalatest.org/)

```
  class ExampleSpec extends FlatSpec with Matchers {

    "A Stack" should "pop values in last-in-first-out order" in {...}
 }
```

As I read it that means "should" is a method of string "A stack"?  If that is right, how does that happen?  It doesn't seem to work from the scala prompt

```
 scala> class ExampleSpec {
 |    "A Stack" should "pop values"
 | }
 <console>:9: error: value should is not a member of String
      "A Stack" should "pop values"
```

If "should" is not a method of string "A Stack" in the above snippet then how am I to read the snippet correctly?  What is "should" and how does it relate to the string?  Any clues?

Comment: If you want that to work in the console, open sbt then type `console` then `import org.scalatest.Matchers`

Answer (score 6):

This is commonly known as the <s>Pimp My Library</s> Enrich My Library pattern where we can extend other libraries (in this case Scala strings) with our own methods by using implicit conversions.

The way it works is that `FlatSpec` mixes in a trait called `ShouldVerb` which has the following implicit conversion defined:

```
 implicit def convertToStringShouldWrapper(o: String): StringShouldWrapperForVerb =
   new StringShouldWrapperForVerb {
     val leftSideString = o.trim
   }
```

And `StringShouldWrapperForVerb` has the `should` method defined:

```
def should(right: String) ....
```

The reason it does not work in the REPL for you is that you don't have `FlatSpec` and via that the `ShouldVerb` trait mixed in.

You can read more about this in the documentation [under implicit classes](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/implicit-classes.html).

Answer (score 2):

In `org.scalatest.Matchers`, an implicit conversion is provided that converts `String` to `StringShouldWrapper`, which is the class that provides the `should` function on `String`:

```
implicit def convertToStringShouldWrapper(o: String): StringShouldWrapper
```

The compiler will *implicitly* convert any `String` to a `StringShouldWrapper` when it encounters that call.  If you call a function on an object that doesn't exist, the compiler will check in-scope implicit conversions (like the one above) to see if any of them will provide that function.

Comment: In this case I think the question is about how the test suite's `should` is done so it comes from `FlatSpec` and not `Matchers`.